# MySQL find number of students in attendance broken down by time

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing arriving and departing times for students attending a class.  Given something like this data:

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `arrival` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `departure` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `attendance` (`id`, `class_id`, `student_id`, `arrival`, `departure`)
VALUES
(1,1,1,'2013-01-01 16:00:00','2013-01-01 17:00:00'),
(2,1,2,'2013-01-01 16:00:00','2013-01-01 18:00:00'),
(3,1,3,'2013-01-01 17:00:00','2013-01-01 19:00:00'),
(4,1,4,'2013-01-01 17:00:00','2013-01-01 19:00:00'),
(5,1,5,'2013-01-01 17:30:00','2013-01-01 18:30:00');
```

I'm trying to get a breakdown of time in minutes, and how many students are present for that time period.  A result something like this from the above data:

```
Time  Students
60    2        (the first hour from 16:00 to 17:00 has students 1 & 2)
30    3        (the next 30 minutes from 17:00 to 17:30 has students 2, 3 & 4)
30    4        (etc...)
30    3
30    2
```

The select statement I have so far is getting some way towards the answer but I can't quite get it working:

```
SELECT a.id, a.arrival, b.id, LEAST(a.departure,b.departure) AS departure,
TIMEDIFF((LEAST(a.departure,b.departure)),(a.arrival)) AS subtime
FROM attendance a
JOIN attendance b ON (a.id <> b.id and a.class_id=b.class_id 
  and a.arrival >= b.arrival and a.arrival < b.departure) 
WHERE a.class_id=1
ORDER BY a.arrival, departure, b.id;
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me get this right.

Comment: you will need to use aggregate functions, look at group by and count(distinct student_id), etc. [read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `correlated sub-queries` you can create virtual tables (not the same as a `temporary table`, but kinda the same idea). You can then query against these virtual tables just as if they really existed.

```
select clocks.clock, count( att.student_id ) as numStudents
from
(
        ( select arrival as clock from attendance )
        union distinct
        ( select departure as clock from attendance )
)
as clocks
        left outer join attendance att on att.arrival <= clocks.clock and clocks.clock < att.departure
group by clocks.clock
order by 1,2
;
```

Almost what you are looking for. Rather than group by elapsed time, this uses the actual 'event' timestamps (arrivals and departures) and gives you a useful report.

```
clock               numStudents 
------------------- ----------- 
2013-01-01 16:00:00 2           
2013-01-01 17:00:00 3           
2013-01-01 17:30:00 4           
2013-01-01 18:00:00 3           
2013-01-01 18:30:00 2           
2013-01-01 19:00:00 0
```

The report shows how many students are still 'here' at each event time.

Hopefully this is useful for you.

Comment: That'll do it!  I can use php to loop through the result set and refine the data.  Thank you very much for your help, @majorbanzai.